# scrollview within a containerview in storyboard not scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, uicontainerview

I have a viewcontroller with one `UIView` on the top and a `containerview` placed right beneath it. Like,

[image]

I'd connected everything with `Autolayout`.

Now, I want to load 4 different `containerviews` in that bottom space(one over the another, since at a time I'll show one containerview only and will hide the rest using `alpha` property of a `UIView`), of which one of the containerview has so many subcomponents(registration page comps), for which I used a `UIScrollview`. The scrollview is not working in this scenario, my question is,

Can I use a scrollview within a containerview?

My scrollview has a UIView in it, which inturn holds the individual components, is that the reason why my scrollview is not working?

Comment: your storyboard hierarchy  should be Scrollview -> ContainterView - > Your Controls (UIVIew, button etc)

Comment: scrollview is required only for a particular containerview and at a time I'll be showing only one containerview. All those containerview contents appear at the same place, I'm just hiding and showing it.

Comment: you should not put multiple container view , either you can have you multiple views  in container view and show hide them .